# Flex and Bison compiler doesn't show lexical errors when he meets one syntax error

Tags: compilation, syntax-error, bison, flex-lexer, lex

I'm coding a compiler using Flex and Bison, I coded yyerror(char*) and some printf() messages to show lexical and syntax errors. I tested my code by adding some errors in my file "programm.txt" in order to show the errors that should be displayed. (for example: `int x = 89754545` is a lexical error that will be displayed because I defined a length limit to integers (max = 5 in length) )

**The problem I met:**

All lexical errors appear one after the other, but when the compiler meets a syntax error :

He shows all lexical errors that occur before the first syntax error.

He shows the first syntax error he meets.

And then he stops compiling without showing the other errors whether they are lexical or syntax errors.

Here's my code:

**lexical.l:**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Taking a problem existing in your actual project and *isolating* it to the point where you have a [mcve] to show is an essential debugging skill. Without seeing your code all we could do is guess. And you also just learned another lessen... sooner or later your code **will** need to be read by somebody else. It is a good idea to keep your code, identifiers and comments, and ideally even the default output language, in English; this makes "getting help" a lot easier. Other than that... (t.b.c.)

Comment: Don't misunderstand me. I didn't share it because I hadn't errors when coding. I throught that there will be some Flex programmers that met such a problem and know how to fix it. I'm going to edit my post and add my code.

Comment: ...my crystal ball would say at the following: You have a lexer (`flex` code) that tokenizes your input, and a parser (`bison` code) that translates it. Your parser code stops at the first error it encounters. *Of course* you will see the lexer / tokenizer errors leading up to that problem first, and unless you took great care to recover from syntax / parsing errors (which is pretty hard to do if even possible) your compiler stops after the first one. So... without seeing a [mcve], I'd say "works as expected"?

Comment: Now you added "your" code, which is one step better than not showing *any* code. Ideal would be if you would take "your" code, and reduce it to a piece of "code showing the problem". It need not actually *do* much, other than exhibiting the problem you are describing. Its main advantage would be that it is *shorter* and does not contain lots of irrelevant code..

Comment: This is actually the problem I want to resolve, I don't know where is my error, because the compiler doesn't show me bugs in my code, the problem is hiden somewhere I couldn't find.

Comment: I call this [Machete Debugging](https://rootdirectory.de/doku.php?id=software:machetedebugging) ;-) By the way, we're still missing `"TS.h"` to be able to compile this... (and a Makefile, if you're feeling generous ;-) )

Comment: You can remove ```TS.h``` from both files. ```TS.h``` is an empty file I didn't fill it yet.

Comment: I added the makefile. :)

Comment: I noticed that even if the yerror(char* ) function is correct, syntax errors don't appear in a correct way. Only the first syntax error is shown. Besides, it displays the wrong line number that should contain the error (if the error in on the 2th line, it shows that it's one 3rd line, and this is because of empty line breaks that he didn't count).

Comment: If you use `%option yylineno`, flex will count the line numbers. It does so accurately and rapidly and without any code beyond that one line. So there's no advantage for you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you add error recovery productions to your grammar, bison will just stop parsing when it encounters a syntax error. So it won't encounter any more errors. It just returns an error value (1).

Furthermore, when the parser stops parsing, it stops asking the scanner for tokens. So no more input will be read, and no more lexical errors will be discovered.

Error recovery is not easy. You probably should work on getting your lexer and parser working on correct inputs first. Once you understand how grammars and lexical scanning works in practice, you'll probably have an easier time adding informative error messages. It's almost always easier to start with short, focussed programs (and grammars) rather than producing hundreds of lines of code whose interactions you don't fully understand.

There is a chapter in the Bison manual about [error recovery](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Recovery). You should definitely read it, but also read through some of the examples which show how to do [simple error recovery](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Simple-Error-Recovery), and the related explanations. There really is quite a lot of useful information in the Bison manual.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thank you ! 